# Is there a way to suppress unresolved imports in eclipse in a PyDev project?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a Python project in eclipse, which imports modules that can't be found by Python. Here's a list of some of the cases:

1. some of the files might *import both the 2.x and 3.x versions* of some built-in modules for compatibility purposes (but I can specify only one grammar version in the project's settings)
2. since the scripts I'm writing will be ran in an environment very different from mine, some of the modules I use don't even exist in the system (*like Windows-specific modules, or modules from other projects that I REALLY don't want to link directly to this one*)
3. modules that might or might not be installed on the machine where the script is going to be executed (of course, wrapped into try-except clauses)
   and so on...

It is very annoying to have these modules marked as errors, since they make REAL syntax errors much less noticeable.
I know that this behavior can somehow be overridden - I have another project that doesn't mark unresolved imports as errors, but I just can't find the right setting for it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

How about adding `#@UnresolvedImport` to your imports? Eg:

```
import a_module_pydev_doesnt_know #@UnresolvedImport
```

You can simply press Ctrl-1 when your cursor is placed in a line where PyDev marked an error and and select the corresponding entry to automatically add it.

*Edit:* I don't have much experience with it, but it seems that if you want to change this for a whole project (or do it without touching your code), you can also add the module in question to the forced built-ins: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins

Comment: Well, it does work, but I'm looking for a more general solution - I don't really want to modify my code like that because 1) I know that it can be done through project settings without any code modification, 2) this is just a small part of a huge SVN repository, and the same code might be edited by someone else in a different IDE/editor or with different modules installed and it wouldn't make much sense in that case if every other line had some strange comments in it...

Comment: True... I just updated the answer with a second option, I hope this one works for you!

Comment: it requires for the modules to exist in the system, but they don't.